# Change field map properties in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, csv, field-mapping

I am trying to import csv files in ArcGIS to do a join. However, some of the fields are identified as double, some as long and some as long. Therefore the join results in bunch of columns with NULL value. I am not sure why it happens.

I tried to save the numbers with three decimal position in excel as csv format but when I open the number after decimal does not change. Since I have more than 256 columns, I can't save it as xls/xlsx file.

I think using python could be a solution. Any other thoughts? Python experts, could you please provide me any help. Attached is the screenshot..

[image: CSV to dbf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bring in a csv, Arc does its best to determine the appropriate field types and as you have found it doesn't always get it right.  One solution is to use a [schema.ini file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000010000000) (see bottom of page) to explicitly set the field types for your columns.  There are several related (duplicate?) questions here on the GIS SE if you search for 'schema.ini'.  More information about your data and its format would be needed for more specific help.

Answer (score -3):

I have arcgis 10 and I think you can not import CSV files into the geodatabase, much less save as .DBF.
First, try to add to ArcMap, then export to geodatabase.